# Setup for upgrading from AngularJS guide - Deprecated repository alternative?

Tags: angular, angularjs, hybrid

I trying to create a hybrid Angularjs and Angular app using this guide https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-from-angularjs-to-angular.
It uses a deprecated repo from this guide https://github.com/angular/quickstart.
Are there alternative repositories by angular to create a hybrid angularjs and angular application?

The deprecated repository throws a syntax error (unexpected Token) error in the console ([browser-dynamic.mjs: Unexpected token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X44Ck.png)) :

```
SyntaxError: http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm2022/platform-browser-dynamic.mjs: Unexpected token (114:11) (at system.js:4:1092)
  112 |         return promise;
  113 |     }
> 114 |     static { this.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.9", ngImport: i0, type: ResourceLoaderImpl, deps: null, target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Injectable }); }
      |            ^
  115 |     static { this.ɵprov = i0.ɵɵngDeclareInjectable({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.9", ngImport: i0, type: ResourceLoaderImpl }); }
  116 | }
  117 | i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "17.0.9", ngImport: i0, type: ResourceLoaderImpl, decorators: [{
    at _.raise (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:533149)
    at aa.unexpected (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:486489)
    at ga.parseIdentifier (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:531425)
    at ga.parsePropertyName (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:528873)
    at ba.parseClassBody (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:499181)
    at ba.parseClass (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:497736)
    at ba.parseStatement (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:487659)
    at ba.parseBlockBody (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:495459)
    at ba.parseTopLevel (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:486625)
    at b.parse (systemjs-babel-browser.js:1:485384)
(anonymous) @ localhost/:106
```

it seems like the systemjs version 0.21.26 is not compatible with the latest syntax in angular platform-browser-dynamic.mjs library.

Did someone manage to solve the error in the attached image?

Thanks.
Natan